# How do I upload a HTML form with a username, password, multiple file uploads and then process it with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

How to post a username, password and multiple binary files from a single html form and process it using php? I'm not allowed to use ajax.

Comment: what do you want to do with this information? save it in a database?

Comment: i need to save the files on the server. the username and password is checked against a database.

Comment: I don't think i understand the question... what are you going to process? What kind of processing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first off check out these pages on PHP.net

1. [file upload info](https://www.php.net/features.file-upload)
2. [`move_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

But to get you started here's a couple stub files.

**uploadForm.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="processStuff.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        username: <input type="text" name="username" />
        password: <input type="password" name="password" />
        
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" /><br />
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" /><br />
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" /><br />
            <!-- Add as many of these as you want -->
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**processStuff.php**

```
<pre>
<?php

    echo '<h2>Username & password</h2>'
    echo "Username: {$_POST['username']}\nPassword: {$_POST['password']}";
    echo '<hr />';

    echo '<h2>Uploaded files</h2>'  
    foreach($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'] as $i => $tempUploadPath) {
        if (empty($tempUploadPath)) {
            // this <input type="file" /> was "blank"... no file selected
        } else {
            // a file was uploaded
            echo '<strong>A file named "', $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'][$i], "\" was uploaded</strong>\n";
            echo "\ttemporarily stored at: ", $tempUploadPath, "\n";            
            echo "\tmime type: ", $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'][$i], "\n";
            echo "\tsize: ", $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'][$i], " bytes\n";         
            echo "\terror code", 
            ((empty($_FILES['uploadFile']['size'][$i]) 
                    ? '<em>no errror</em>' 
                    : $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'][$i])), 
            "\n\n";
        
    // do something useful with the uploaded file 
        // access it via $tempUploadPath and use move_uploaded_file() to move 
        //     it out of the temp path before you manipulate it in any way!!!!!
        // see https://www.php.net/features.file-upload
        // and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php
        }       
    }

?>
</pre>
```

The HTML file shows how to set the `enctype` of the `<form>` & the second form show you how to access the submitted username & password & finally how to loop thru every uploaded file.

As noted you MUST move the file(s) ASAP. They're uploaded to a temp location and the system will delete them unless you deal with them. So move 'em somewhere first then do whatever you need w/ them.

Hoep this helps

Arin

Comment: there seem to be two ; missing at the end of the following lines:

    echo '<h2>Username & password</h2>'

    echo '<h2>Uploaded files</h2>'

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$_FILES` superglobal and `move_uploaded_file()` function to see which files were uploaded successfully and move them to their final location in case they were.

The `$_POST` superglobal will contain the submitted username and password.